# How to change column name in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to get aws cost using cost explorer api, following is code I am using here.

The output I am getting in column name (2021-02-01) that I want to convert to (Feb-21). Can someone guide me what changes I have to make and in which line in following code

```
rows = []
    sort = ''
    for v in results:
        
   
        row = {'date':v['TimePeriod']['Start']}
        sort = v['TimePeriod']['Start']
        for i in v['Groups']:
            key = i['Keys'][0]
            if key in self.accounts:
                key = self.accounts[key][ACCOUNT_Name]
            row.update({key:int(float(i['Metrics']['UnblendedCost']['Amount']))}) 
        if not v['Groups']:
            row.update({'Total':int(float(v['Total']['UnblendedCost']['Amount']))})
        rows.append(row)  
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows)

    df.set_index('date', inplace= True)
    
    df = df.fillna(0.0)
    
    if Style == 'Change':
        dfc = df.copy()
        lastindex = None
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            if lastindex:
                for i in row.index:
                    try:
                        df.at[index,i] = dfc.at[index,i] - dfc.at[lastindex,i]
                    except:
                        logging.exception("Error")
                        df.at[index,i] = 0
            lastindex = index
    df = df.T
    df = df.sort_values(sort, ascending=False)
    self.reports.append({'Name':Name,'Data':df, 'Type':type})
```

Output that i get

2021-02-01      2021-02-01
xxxxxxx          xxxxxxx

output required

Jan-21           Feb-21
xxxxxxx          xxxxxxx

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the format as below,

df['col1'] = df['col'].dt.strftime('%b-%y')

Comment: can you guide me where i have to put this in code